# Query error with parameter passing - Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to query the database, with hibernate, and when I pass the parameters I get the following error.

Could you help me?

```
    public List<Viaje> getListaViajes(Localizacion idOrigen, Localizacion idDestino, SessionFactory _SessionBuilder) {

        Session sesion = _SessionBuilder.openSession();

        Query origen = sesion.createQuery("from Localizacion where nombre = :nombreLocalizacion");

        origen.setParameter("nombreLocalizacion", idOrigen.getNombre());
        Localizacion idOrigen2 = (Localizacion) origen.uniqueResult();
        
        System.out.println(idOrigen2.getId() + " ES SU ID.");
```

Error:

```
Información:   from Localizacion where nombre = (:nombreLocalizacion)
Información:   Hibernate: select localizaci0_.ID as ID1_8_, localizaci0_.Nombre as Nombre2_8_, localizaci0_.estacion as estacion3_8_, localizaci0_.latitud as latitud4_8_, localizaci0_.longitud as longitud5_8_ from bd_viajes_sig.localizacion localizaci0_ where (nombre=(?))
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[ControladorAjaxDestinosDisponibles]: Servlet.service() for servlet ControladorAjaxDestinosDisponibles threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The problem is that this line does not work, since the value that corresponds to the query is not set:

```
origen.setParameter("nombreLocalizacion", idOrigen.getNombre());
```

Instead if I put in the query, if it works.

```
Query origen = sesion.createQuery("from Localizacion where nombre = 'España');
```

The method idOrigen.getNombre() it works properly so that's not the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely where you null is being thrown:

```
Localizacion idOrigen2 = (Localizacion) origen.uniqueResult();
```

`origen` is null. Verify that it is not null first before trying to access the result. Also make sure you are passing the correct value to your query. I do not see where in method nombreLocalizacion is set. This could be another issue as well.

Comment: Sorry, I did not copy the nombreLocalizacion part, I have modified the code again with some more clarifications, if you can check it again I would appreciate it, thank you very much.